# How to correct css3 nav ul a:active background padding issue

Tags: html, css, background, padding

I'm working on my website and am having a brain meltdown today.

First here's where I'm at:
http://www.lenniemoore.com/home.html
And the related css files:
http://www.lenniemoore.com/assets/desktop.css

On my nav bar menu, I have everything styled and working fine with the background colors EXCEPT for the a:active element. When I click or click and hold the mouse button on a menu item the background shape is not the same shape as the other elements.

I think it's a padding issue but I've been combing thru all my css all day and just am not seeing the culprit.

Here's the related css code from desktop.css:

```
    ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0 0 5px -35px;}
    .content ul,.content ol{padding:0 15px 15px 40px;}
    #navigator nav{clear:both;width:950px;padding:4px 0;background:#06c;background:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(0,40,80,0),rgba(0,40,80,0.5)),#06c;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,40,80,0)),to(rgba(0,40,80,0.5))),#06c;background:-o-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,40,80,0)),to(rgba(0,40,80,0.5))),#06c;overflow:auto;border-radius:20px;box-shadow:-3px 3px 2px rgba(64,64,55,0.4);}
    nav ul a,nav ul a:visited{padding:0;margin:0 0 2px 0;display:block;}
    nav li,nav li a{-moz-transition-duration:0.25s;-webkit-transition-duration:0.25s;-o-transition-duration:0.25s;}
    nav li{float:left;width:130px;padding:0 0 5px 0;margin:0 5px 0 0;}
    nav li a{display:block;text-align:center;line-height:normal;vertical-align:middle;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold; text-shadow:-2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1),0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);text-decoration:none;color:#eee;}
    nav ul a,nav ul a:visited,nav ul a:focus,nav ul a:active,nav li,nav li.current{border-radius:13px;}
    nav ul a:focus,nav ul a:active,nav li.current,nav li:hover{box-shadow:0px 1px 5px black;}
    nav ul a:focus,nav ul a:active,nav li.current{background:#900;background:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0)),#900;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0))),#900;background:-o-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0))),#900;color:#eec;text-shadow:-1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1),-2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
    nav li:hover{background:#ffd;background:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0)),#ffd;background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0))),#ffd;background:-o-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),to(rgba(0,0,0,0))),#ffd;}
    nav li:hover a{color:#900;text-shadow:-2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1),-3px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have `padding: 0 0 5px 0;` set on `nav li`. If you remove that, and instead place it on `nav ul a, nav ul a:visited` then your problem will be fixed.

Basically, the padding on the list item meant that the anchor could never reach the same height. By placing that padding on the anchor instead, both elements are the same height.

Comment: Thanks. I've done what you suggested (and it makes perfect sense) but I'm still not finding the solution yet. Going spelunking into the CSS files this morning and seeing if I can isolate the problem...

Comment: Found it! It was a combo of what I had going on between two css files, plus extra margin values in    nav ul a, nav ul a:visited

Comment: Cool, that it's all working! Strange the my solution didn't work. It fixed it perfectly on my end. Shall I delete my answer?

Comment: Nah your answer works in normal situations. Keep in mind I had two css files, normalize.css and desktop.css and some of conflict arose between the two files.

Comment: Yup, sorry for not being quicker on that. I'm actually a video game composer, not a web designer. But I am fairly technically skilled enough to eventually figure this stuff out